# Converting a math function to allow for multiple values

Tags: math, vectorization, octave, fibonacci

I'm trying to alter an Octave / Matlab Function to allow for multiple values.

Example: the function **rtfib(8)** produces **21** which is the 8th Fibonacci number.

I'm trying to have the input to also allow **rtfib(1:8)** and the answer will come back as an array **[1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21]**

My code is below:

```
function [f] = rtfib(n)

  if n<0
    multi=-1; %if neg number store neg in multi variable
    n=abs(n); %if neg make pos
  else
    multi=1;
  end


  if (n == 0)
    f = 0;
  elseif (n==1)
    f=1;
  elseif (n == 2)
    f = 1;    % its 1
  else
    fOld = 1; % 1 again.
    fOlder = 1;
    for i = 3 : n
      f = fOld + fOlder;
      fOlder = fOld;
      fOld = f;
    end
  end
  f=f*multi; %put sign back

end
```

PS: I'm using Octave 4.2.2 which is similar to Matlab

Comment: You compute the full sequence up to n in your code. If you save those values, and compute the sequence up to `max(n)`, then a simple indexing operation gets you the output for each element of `n` if `n` is a vector.

Comment: Note also the function `sign`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Faster Approach - using 1-single for loop***

---

```
function a = rtfib(n)

if numel(n) == 1
    len = n;
else
    len = numel(n);
end

result = zeros(1, numel(n));

result(1) = 1;
result(2) = 1;

for j=3:len
    result(j) = bsxfun(@plus, result(j-1), result(j-2));
end

if numel(n) == 1
    a = result(len);
else
    a = result;
end
end
```

For `rtfib(8)`:

```
ans =

    21
```

For `rtfib(1:8)`

```
ans =

     1     1     2     3     5     8    13    21
```

***Without Changing the logic Approach***

---

We should return the result as a vector, whether the input is a single integer or an array. Therefore I modified the function return `a` instead of `f`.

```matlab
function a = rtfib(n)
a = [];
```

Then, we need to check whether the input is an integer or an array, using `numel`. Since `numel` returns 1 for a single integer and returns array-size for the array.

For each integer in `n`, calculate the Fibonacci value.

```matlab
for j=1:numel(n)

    % Without changing the logic.

    a = [a, f*multi]; %put sign back
end
```

Code:

```matlab
function a = rtfib(n)
a = [];
for j=1:numel(n)
    if n(j)<0
        multi=-1; %if neg number store neg in multi variable
        n(j)=abs(n(j)); %if neg make pos
    else
        multi=1;
    end
    
    if (n(j) == 0)
        f = 0;
    elseif (n(j)==1)
        f=1;
    elseif (n(j) == 2)
        f = 1;    % its 1
    else
        fOld = 1; % 1 again.
        fOlder = 1;
        for i = 3 : n(j)
            f = fOld + fOlder;
            fOlder = fOld;
            fOld = f;
        end
    end
    a=[a, f*multi]; %put sign back
end
end
```

Comment: 1) Preallocate. Preallocate preallocate preallocate. 2) For an input vector of size `k`, your solution calculates `rtfib(1)` `k` times. It calculates `rtfib(5)` `k-4` times. Why not calculate *all* of the numbers *once* and then pick the ones you need to return? 3) On the plus side, your solution does handle non-sequential input vectors.

Comment: I've updated my answer, "Faster Approach - using 1-single for loop" title is added.

Comment: See my [comment below the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63653760/converting-a-math-function-to-allow-for-multiple-values#comment112575852_63653760). `result` is part of the answer. You need to compute your `result` up to `max(n)`, then return `result(n)`. This will allow for arbitrary inputs like `rtfib([8,3,16,6])`.

Comment: Well I believe I answer the OP's question, in both approaches, faster and without changing the logic

Comment: @Ahmet I have to disagree with you. Your original solution is very slow, and your updated solution fails on certain types of input (such as negative values, non-sequential values, and ranges that start with a value other than 1) and is rather convoluted (neither `if/else` block is needed, nor is `bsxfun`).

Answer (score 2):

This function works also with scalars, sequential vectors, non-sequential vectors, and matrices. In addition, the output has the same dimensions of the input:

```
function res = rtfib(n)
    abs_mat = abs(n);
    max_num = max(max(abs_mat));
    
    fib_vec = ones(1, max_num);
    for i = 3:max_num
        fib_vec(i) = fib_vec(i - 1) + fib_vec(i - 2);
    end
    
    res = zeros(size(n));
    res(n ~= 0) = fib_vec(abs_mat(n ~= 0));
    res(n < 0) = -res(n < 0);
end
```

**Examples:**

Code:

```
n = 9
rtfib(n)
```

Output:

```
n =  9
ans =  34
```

Code:

```
n = 1:8
rtfib(n)
```

Output:

```
n =

   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8

ans =

    1    1    2    3    5    8   13   21
```

Code:

```
n = [1:8]'
rtfib(n)
```

Output:

```
n =

   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8

ans =

    1
    1
    2
    3
    5
    8
   13
   21
```

Code:

```
n = [-5 1 6 0; 4 4 -2 8; 7 -3 0 -1]
rtfib(n)
```

Output:

```
n =

  -5   1   6   0
   4   4  -2   8
   7  -3   0  -1

ans =

   -5    1    8    0
    3    3   -1   21
   13   -2    0   -1
```